# How can I use pets effectively?

Tags: pixel-piracy

I have captured a couple of pets in Pixel Piracy, and am not quite sure how to effectively use them. I try carefully to get them **xp** without getting them killed, but they require *sooo much*. They just distract me from keeping my main pirates safe in battle.

Can they be used tactically or are they just a novelty?